# why the distance of carousel is too far from its controls?

Tags: html, jquery, css, owl-carousel, bootstrap-grid

I have a carouse, the items inside it is split by two columns using Bootstrap Grid System. One column is some text and the rest column contains another carousel.

This is my code:

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
    autoheight: true,
});

$('.store__img-slider').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
    autoheight: true,
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                       <h1>Some text...</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="https://picsum.photos/530/350" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="https://picsum.photos/530/350" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="https://picsum.photos/530/350" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="https://picsum.photos/530/350" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="https://picsum.photos/530/350" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                       <h1>Some text...</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="https://picsum.photos/530/350" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="https://picsum.photos/530/350" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="https://picsum.photos/530/350" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="https://picsum.photos/530/350" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="https://picsum.photos/530/350" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, why the distance of carousel is too far from its controls (nav, dots button, ...)?
but when I resize the windows, it changed the distance

I used Owl Carousel 2 + jQuery + Bootstrap Grid System